# How do I pass a variable to angular library

Tags: javascript, angular

So I have an Angular library with a service installed on my main project and I want to know if it's possible to retrieve a global url variable or a field of my config.json file I defined in my main project. Would be nice to know how too.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Answer (score 1):

In the src/environments/ folder you can have an environment.ts file with settings variables and use it with

`import { environment } from './../environments/environment';`

Then any variable you have in the file will be available.

You can even have different files for each of your environments.

https://angular.io/guide/build